# Calculating Moebius inversion of a poset with a minimum element.

Tags: mobius-inversion

If P is a poset that has a minimum element. We let x be an element of P that covers 1 single element y.Assume that y is not the minimum element, how do I prove that μ(minimum element,x) = 0?

So μ(min, min) + μ(min , closest element that covers min) = 0, 
and μ(x,z) = $-∑_{x<y<z}μ(x,y)$
but how do i prove that the value of  μ(minimum element, y)is fixed?

I've spent some time looking at this and can't figure it out. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Let $0$ be the minimum element of $P$.

Since $x$ only covers $y$,
$$
\mu(0,x) 
\;=\; 
\sum_{0\leqslant z\leqslant x}\mu(0,z)
\:-\:
\sum_{0\leqslant z\leqslant y}\mu(0,z)
\;=\;
0 \:-\: 0
\;=\;
0
.
$$